# What is this ringing in the inductor current?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, power-electronics, inductor, buck

I am working on a buck-boost converter and I see this ringing in the inductor current. It happens on turn on of the high side FET (See attached Image). First of all is this ringing normal?
Is there any way to fix it?

Another question - Why is this not happening on the Turn on of the Low side FET, when the current is at is peak?[image]

I appreciate your answers and thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: I've seen MOSFET lead(s) though small ferrite beads/cores; that could help reduce ringing.

Comment: How/with what are you probing the inductor current? Also, do you have a near-field EM probe (H loop)?

Answer (score 3):

Ringing is not unusual in dc-dc converter circuits. Every inductor has some capacitance, and every capacitor has some inductance, and pair of conductors has both. The only way to definitely avoid ringing is to dampen sections of the circuit that ring. This means adding resistances which means dissipating/wasting some power. So there is an engineering tradeoff to be made. Lower efficiency vs lower ringing.

So is the ringing excessive in your case? That depends upon what happens in the worst case, and upon the components you use. Just by my eyeballs, I would believe it is not excessive, but from your vantage point there may or may not be an issue.

Addendum. If this is a "synchronous" converter, the impulse for ringing generally comes from the dead-time when both high side and low side switches are off. Adjusting the dead time to be shorter can reduce the impulse converted to ringing, at the risk of causing shoot-through. Shoot-through will again cause energy loss, so you have another balancing act. There is a sweet spot, but again, I don't have the information to tell you where that is.

Answer (score 3):

When the high side turns on (after the slow side turns off), the low side has been acting as a diode, and this diode has a stored charge (capacitance). Turning on the high side means it has to supply the diodes pn junction stored charge and since the HS isn't generally current limited, there is nothing to restrict the peak value of the current that begins to reverse bias the diode. This frequently means that the peak HS current can reach over 3x the total inductor current.

Conversely, the LS turning on is just to short out its body diode -- there isn't much change in the signals around the inductor, so no ringing will be observed.